# Angular 7 Lazy loading With Authentication

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7

I am trying to lazy load module from my-app module. But, It is not get lazy loaded and as well as the URL navigation is not working properly. When I am trying access my lazy load module component, I got errors like following....

```
core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map ()
    at webpackAsyncContext ($_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:21)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:17170)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:17162)
    at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:3608)
    at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:3596)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.js:2605)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Array.map ()
    at webpackAsyncContext ($_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:21)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:17170)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:17162)
    at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:3608)
    at RouterConfigLoader.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:3596)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.js:2605)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
```

**App routing**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './shared/home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './Error/page-not-found/page-not- 
found.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './authentication/auth.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
   {
     path: 'users',
     canLoad: [AuthGuard],
     loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule',
     data: {role: 'user'}
   },
   { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
 ];
 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true, useHash: 
 true})],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**User module routing**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';   
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
import { PaymentComponent } from './payment/payment.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CartComponent},
    { path: 'payment', component: PaymentComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Try to rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your routing is failed in Angular 7. But when I build the sample app it's working fine.

Please try below with below code.

**Step 1:** created `admin` area as lazy-loading and created lazy-loading route in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Step 2:** HTML for route path

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin">Admin </a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Step 3:** admin-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

**Step 4:** admin.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, AdminRoutingModule]
})
export class AdminModule { 
}
```

Comment: I am having same code in my sample project....But, it is not working well

Comment: I have attached my sample project code with my question